# c++ pointers to integers giving different answers when subtracted

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int* a = (int*)50;//printf("%d",a)-gives 50
   int* b = (int*)2;//printf("%d",b)-gives 2

  printf("%d",a-b);//12 is answer, but shouldnt it be 50-2=48
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to know why is the answer 12, as it can either be 50-2=48, or 5-2=3.

Comment: It is UB, because You can't assigned directly value to pointer.

Comment: "why does a-b become 12 ? Whats the underlying logic of this?"  see first comment.   UB means there is no logic. Result could be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a pointer to an object of type `T`, the numerical difference between a pointer and its +1 is `sizeof(T)`.

```
T* p1 = <some pointer value>;
T* p2 = p1 + 1;
```

Given the above,

`(p2 - p1)` is `1`.

However, if you take the numerical values of the pointers, if `p1` is `a1,` then `p2` will be `a1 + sizeof(T)`.

Say you have a pointer to an `int` and `sizeof(int)` is 4.

```
 a1                  a2
 |                   |
 v                   v
 +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
 +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

and the value of `p1` is the address `a1`. `p1+1` points to next integer after `a1`, which means it will be `a2`. As you can see the numerical difference between `a1` and `a2` is not 1 but `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer arithmetic operates with knowledge of the underlying type.  When you add a value to a pointer, you add that number of *elements of the underlying type*, not the number of *bytes*.   Similarly for subtraction of two pointers,  the difference is in number of elements, not number of bytes.

Your pointers are of type `int *`.  Based on your output, it seems that an `int` is 4 bytes in length.  So two pointers of this type that differ in value by 48 actually differ in 48 / 4 = 12 `int`s.  So that is the result of the subtraction.

As an aside, assigning a specific numeric value to a pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as does subtracting two pointers that do not point to the same array object.  You do this in a conformant way by creating an array and assigning `a` and `b` the address of two of these elements:

```
int array[60];
int *a = &array[2];
int *b = &array[50];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are initializing your pointers incorrectly, which is leading to [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The behavior of undefined behavior is unspecified, so theoretically, anything could happen, such as the printing of the value 12, which is probably the difference in memory of the pointers. Use the following with the [`new` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) to properly initialize your pointers:

```
int* a = new int{50};
int* b = new int{2};
```

Next, to print the difference of these values, you have to dereference the pointers to get their pointed values:

```
printf("%d",*a-*b);
```

Comment: but why does a-b become 12 ? Whats the underlying logic of this?

Comment: @chetant That is undefined behavior. Assigning a value directly to a pointer could lead to _anything_ happening.

Comment: @chetant • The underlying logic of undefined behavior is "don't do undefined behavior".